# Trying to get an element from a template

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get an element from my template in different ways, but none of them seems to work.
This is my code:

```html
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">       
  <div id="main-content">
     <h1>Main Content</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
angular.module("mainModule", [])
    .controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", "$document", function ($scope, $document) {
      $scope.init = function() {
        var element = angular.element("#main-content");
        console.log(element);
        element = angular.element("main-content");
        console.log(element);
        element = $document.find("#main-content");
        console.log(element);
      }();
    }]);
```

Maybe one of you got any idea? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a [Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for that. 
[AngularJS controller should NEVER reference DOM elements](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/02/19/angularjs-and-dom-manipulation.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid DOM manipulation when working with angular. But if you still want to do it: below is the way to get hold of the element you need :

```
       angular.element(document.querySelector('#main-content'))
```

also you can do it with $element service

```
        $element.find('#main-content')
```